# Does SuperDrive read 8GB DVDs?

Tags: data-transfer, data-recovery, optical-drive, dvd, data

I would like to read some old 8GB DVDs I burned on Windows years ago. Does Apple SuperDrive read that discs?

[image]

Reference:

- https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD564LL/A/apple-usb-superdrive
- [https://www.amazon.com/Memorex-8-5-Double-Layer-DVD/dp/B000UWX70S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000UWX70S)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BR_DL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, by 8GB DVDs, you mean they're [DVD+R DL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BR_DL) DVDs, then the answer is yes.

The Apple SuperDrive supports the following media types:

- CD-R, CD-ROM, CD-RW
- DVD+R, DVD+R DL, DVD+RW, DVD-ROM